# FBResult object doesn't return anything in Unity , Facebook sdk

Tags: android, ios, facebook, sdk, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use facebook sdk to track total app installs. The unity plugin is working for log in, posting etc. But the FB.PublishInstall method doesn't work. I logged the FBResult object and printed it :

```
private void CallFBPublishInstall()
{
    FB.PublishInstall(PublishComplete);

}

private void PublishComplete(FBResult result)
{
    Debug.Log("publish response: " + result.Text.Length);
}
```

This is printed in logcat:

> publish response: 0

I am totally puzzled what is wrong. The installs are not being counted in the app's dashboard in facebook. Anyone knows what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why there is no reponse text. But the installs are now appearing in the app's dashboard. I am guessing it takes time for the counter to kick in.